# How to copy an instance of element while dragging in qml?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I am using the following code to drag. But it actually moves the original element. Instead i require a copied object to be dragged , which wil be destroyed on drop .
  `drag.active: dragarea.drag.active
Mousearea{
Id : dragarea
Anchors.fill : parent
Drag.target: parent
 }`

Comment: I'm facing the same issue... I know it's been a long-while but I wonder if you found a solution...

Answer (score 1):

Read [Dynamic QML Object Creation from JavaScript](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-dynamicobjectcreation.html). It will describe two options:

[Creating a Component Dynamically](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-dynamicobjectcreation.html#creating-a-component-dynamically)

> To dynamically load a component defined in a QML file, call the Qt.createComponent() function in the Qt object. This function takes the URL of the QML file as its only argument and creates a Component object from this URL.
>
> Once you have a Component, you can call its createObject() method to create an instance of the component.

[Creating an Object from a String of QML](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-dynamicobjectcreation.html#creating-an-object-from-a-string-of-qml)

> If the QML is not defined until runtime, you can create a QML object from a string of QML using the Qt.createQmlObject() function

That documentation also has information on how to delete the objects when you're done with them.

You can also use a [`Loader`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html):

> Loader is used to dynamically load QML components.
>
> Loader can load a QML file (using the source property) or a Component object (using the sourceComponent property). It is useful for delaying the creation of a component until it is required: for example, when a component should be created on demand, or when a component should not be created unnecessarily for performance reasons.

Again, destruction of the dynamically loaded item is documented there, too.